# How to overwrite internal component state from the outside

Tags: reactjs, use-state, react-state, react-tsx

I have a rather simple `NumberInput` component/control which handles its internal state (its current value) with `useState`. The "outside world" is not interested in this state but only receives updates via the callback function `onSubmit` which is called on enter & blur.

I also have a component called `MinMaxNumberInputs` which is built of 2 `NumberInput`s. Those 2 `NumberInput`s don't know anything from each other and the parent `MinMaxNumberInputs` has to deal with some "value syncing" by e.g. ensuring that min <= max etc.

This last part is where I'm a little stuck, as I don't know how to "force set" or override the internal state of the `NumberInput`s from `MinMaxNumberInputs` when needed.

Probably best explained via code:

**NumberInput.tsx**

```
// ...

type NumberInputProps = {
  value: number;
  onSubmit: (value: number) => void;
};

export default function NumberInput(props: NumberInputProps) {
  // [1] props.value is obviously only applied on creation.
  //     Future changes have no effect.
  const [value, setValue] = useState(props.value);

  // Called on enter & blur
  const submitValue = () => props.onSubmit(value);

  // ...

  return <input value={value} {/* ... */} />;
}
```

**MinMaxNumberInputs.tsx**

```
// ...

export const MinMaxValueInput = () => {
  // Only for simpler showcasing, using global redux state in real world...
  const [minValue, setMinValue] = useState(0);
  const [maxValue, setMaxValue] = useState(0);

  const onMinValueChanged = (newMinValue: number) => {
    // [2] Ensure that entered value (min here) stays the same but adjust max if required
    //     ??? How to set adjusted value in max NumberInput ???
    const newMaxValue = Math.max(newMinValue, maxValue);
    setMinValue(newMinValue);
    setMaxValue(newMaxValue);
  };

  const onMaxValueChanged = (newMaxValue: number) => {
    // [3] Ensure that entered value (max here) stays the same but adjust min if required
    //     ??? How to set adjusted value in min NumberInput ???
    const newMinValue = Math.min(minValue, newMaxValue);
    setMinValue(newMinValue);
    setMaxValue(newMaxValue);
  };

  // ...

  return (
    <>
      <NumberInput value={minValue} onSubmit={onMinValueChanged} />
      <NumberInput value={maxValue} onSubmit={onMaxValueChanged} />
    </>
  );
};
```

The thing is:

When `newMaxValue` is adjusted in [2] (or `newMinValue` in [3]), `MinMaxNumberInputs` is holding the correct adjusted values in its state but those values are not propagated to the according `NumberInput` and the shown values are therefore not updated/corrected.

I fully understand why this is not working. The `value` property is only applied once to the `NumberInput`s internal state at [1] but not anymore afterwards. However, I have no idea on how to overcome this without "breaking the boundaries" of the `NumberInput` (e.g. using some global state there as well, ...).

I'd really appreciate some guidance on this!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `NumberInput` is **UNCONTROLLED** component, your interface is misleading, it should be named `initialValue` instead of `value`.

Therefore what you want is whats called a "hybrid component", in this case when you DO pass `value` prop, it becomes **CONTROLLED**:

```
export default function NumberInput(props: NumberInputProps) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(props.initialValue);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(props.value)
  }, [props.value])

  return <input value={value}  />;
}
```